# How to compile an independent executable file by g++?

Tags: c++, g++, executable, libraries

I devellop a piece of c++ software on my OpenSUSE, which I like to test on another OpenSUSE system.

I copied the executable file on the other system, but when I am starting it I receive an error:

> "error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system.so.1.61.0:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

How can I compile an independent executable without dependencies?

Eclipse does this:

```
17:24:41 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project boostServer ****
make all 
Building file: ../src/boostCom.cpp
Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler
g++ -I/opt/boost -I/usr/local/lib -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -isystem /opt/boost -MMD -MP -MF"src/boostCom.d" -MT"src/boostCom.o" -o "src/boostCom.o" "../src/boostCom.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/boostCom.cpp

Building file: ../src/main.cpp
Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler
g++ -I/opt/boost -I/usr/local/lib -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -isystem /opt/boost -MMD -MP -MF"src/main.d" -MT"src/main.o" -o "src/main.o" "../src/main.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/main.cpp

Building target: boostServer
Invoking: Cross G++ Linker
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -o "boostServer"  ./src/boostCom.o ./src/boostServer.o ./src/main.o   -lboost_system -lboost_serialization -lboost_thread -lboost_date_time -lpthread
Finished building target: boostServer
```

Greets Ulf

Comment: You may be could use static linkage.

Comment: @Ulf use `-static` in the linkage g++. (i.e the last one in your list), then, if there are static libs it will prefer them opon shared.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have the boost libraries installed on your system, and that the path to them is included in you `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable.

For example, if the `libboost_system.so` file (or symlink) is to be found at `/usr/local/boost-1.56.0/lib64` on your system, then you would run the command.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/boost-1.56.0/lib64`
```

To find out exactly which libraries you need, you can run the command:

```
ldd my_binary
```

The output will tell you exactly which libraries are required, and which of those can't currently be resolved.

Comment: Do I need to install always all used libraries on other systems? Can't I included it in the executable?

Comment: No, not all - just the ones needed by the binary you're trying to run. I've updated my answer to show how this can be done

Comment: Alright, and how does this works if I cross compile for a windows machine by mingw? The *.exe file should include everything.

Comment: Oh jeez... well then you can use the `-static` option on your final build line as SHR suggested in comment above, which will work assuming you have the static version of boost available and the compiler can find them. You can use `b2` with the `link=static` option to build them if you haven't got them. But generally, cross-compiling for windows from a linux box? I seriously wish you good luck. It is technically possible but you may find you have a LOT of headaches before you get there.

Comment: static works for the boost libraries, but not for these: cannot find -lpthread -lm and -lc

Comment: yes, I noticed it is painful to make cross compiling for windows

Comment: Well, you can mix static and dynamic linking by alternating a slightly different set of options, like this: `g++ ...  -Wl,-Bstatic -lboost_system ...  -Wl,-Bdynamic -lpthread`. This might compile but you'll need a lot more work to produce a working windows binary